# range() function is giving me trouble

Tags: python, range

If I were to type something like this, I would get these values:

```
print range(1,10) 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

but say if I want to use this same value in a `for` loop then it would instead start at 0, an example of what I mean:

```
for r in range(1,10):
    for c in range(r): 
        print c,
    print ""
```

The Output is this:

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Why is 0 here? shouldn't it start at 1 and end in 9?

Comment: what is `range(1),range(2)` etc..

Comment: `>>> range(1) #=> [0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a *second* `range()` object in your loop. The default start value is `0`.

Each iteration you create a loop over `range(r)`, meaning *range from 0 to `r`, exclusive*, to produce the output numbers. For `range(1)` that means you get a list with just `[0]` in it, for `range(1)` you get `[0, 1]`, etc.

If you wanted to produce ranges from 1 to `r` *inclusive*`, just add 1 to the number you actually print:

```
for r in range(1,10):
    for c in range(r): 
        print c + 1,
    print ""
```

or range from 1 to `r + 1`:

```
for r in range(1,10):
    for c in range(1, r + 1): 
        print c,
    print ""
```

Both produce your expected output:

```
>>> for r in range(1,10):
...     for c in range(r): 
...         print c + 1,
...     print ""
... 
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
>>> for r in range(1,10):
...     for c in range(1, r + 1): 
...         print c,
...     print ""
... 
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you pass only one argument to [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function, it would treat that as the ending value  (without including it), starting from zero.
- If you pass two arguments to the `range` function, it would treat the first value as the starting value and the second value as the ending value (without including it).
- If you pass three arguments to the `range` function, it would treat the first value as the starting value and the second value as the ending value (without including it) and the third value as the step value.

You can confirm this with few trial runs like this

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    # Default start value 0
>>> range(5, 10)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                   # Starts from 5
>>> range(5, 10, 2)
[5, 7, 9]                         # Starts from 5 & takes only the 2nd element
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

```
for r in range(1,10):
    for c in range(r): 
        print c,
    print ""
```

`range()`, when only given one argument, prints the numbers from 0 to the argument, not including the argument:

```
>>> range(6)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And so, on the third iteration of your code, this is what happens:

```
for r in range(1,10): # r is 3
    for c in range(r): # range(3) is [0,1,2]
        print c, #you then print each of the range(3), giving the output you observe
    print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

From the docs:

The arguments must be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0.